# PhpStorm - copy & paste removes indentation

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

If I copy paste indented text e.g.:

```
foo
    bar
        123
```

to PhpStorm, then the formatting and indentation gets lost.

[image]

My PhpStorm is fresh installed

Comment: Have you tried changing the option `File | Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Reformat on paste` ?

Comment: Yes, "indent each line" is  currently selected which is default.

Comment: And if you set it to `None`, because that seems to do it at my end

Comment: I just selected `none` and now it seems to work. Thanks for your hint

Comment: @RonNabuurs, Please make an answer so I can accept your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the option `File | Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Reformat on paste` to `None`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your global settings, you may also use `Past Simple` option to ad-hoc skip autoformatting on paste.

[image]